# Return Optional as it is if the returned Optional has value, else call another function

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, flatmap

I have two methods func1 and func2 which return Optional.
Return Optional as it is if the returned Optional from func1 has value, else call func2 and return its Optional. 
One way is to use `if-else`.

```
Optional<MyObject> opt1 = func1();
if (opt1.isPresent()) {
    return opt1;
}
return func2();
```

However, I wish to achieve it using Java 8 Optional and avoid `if-else`.

Something like:

```
return Optional.of(obj1) 
        .flatMap_returnOptionalIfvaluePresent(func1)
        .orElseReturnOptionalFromThis(func2)
```

Can anyone suggest a good way for it?

Comment: What is `func1` and `func2`? If they are methods, please reformat your code to be valid. Provide the expected inputs and desired outputs. Provide the `if-else` to make the question clearer.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a clear and simple `if-else` for a hard-to-read way ?

Comment: This has the potential to be a good question but it's currently not clear what you want. Post your code that uses `if-else` so that its obvious what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Michael I am with you here, if the OP comes to explain more, this has the potential to be a fairly good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Edit: `or`

Java 9 and later offer a very elegant solution:

```
Optional<String> myFunc() {
    return func1().or(this::func2);
}
```

`or` (introduced in Java 9) does exactly what you asked for: If the `Optional` returned from `func1` has a value, it is returned (or an equivalent `Optional`). If not, the supplier (here `func2()`) is invoked to get an `Optional`, which is then returned.

### Java 8

There are several ways. In Java 8 I prefer to take the values out of the `Optional`s from `func1` and `func2`:

```
Optional<String> myFunc() {
    String returnValue = func1().orElse(func2().orElse(null));
    return Optional.ofNullable(returnValue);
}
```

**Edit 2:** @Holger’s alternative suggestion in a comment is good enough for quoting within the answer (Holger, you may have posted it as a comment only because the question is closed and you therefore could not post your own answer):

```
    return func1().map(Optional::of).orElse(func2());
```

It goes the opposite way: The mapping using `Optional::of` wraps the `Optional` from `func1` inside yet an `Optional` only if it has a value, from which `orElse` unwraps it again.

If the call to `func2` is expensive, you may want to avoid it when it’s not needed (when `func1` supplies a value):

```
    String returnValue = func1().orElseGet(() -> func2().orElse(null));
```

Or in Holger’s version:

```
    return func1().map(Optional::of).orElseGet(this::func2);
```

`isPresent` used in a couple of other answers is so low-level, I seldom use it and only as a last resort.

Comment: Is there any Optional API to eliminate `return Optional.ofNullable(returnValue);`

Comment: No, @adimoh, but you may of course inline it if you prefer: `return Optional.ofNullable(func1().orElse(func2().orElse(null)));`.

Comment: @OleV.V. the java-9 `or` is the way to go here, but at the same time I see nothing wrong with something like `public static <T> Optional<T> find(Optional<T> left, Optional<T> right) {
        return left.isPresent() ? left : right;
    }`.. 1+

Comment: Using `func1().orElseGet(() -> func2().orElse(null))` will bring a slight improvement as `func2` wouldn't be executed eagerly. Good solutions though.

Comment: Yes, @ernest_k, that’s exactly what I say near the bottom of the answer. Great minds think alike. :-)

Comment: @Michael A very near duplicate. That question doesn’t have the method calls to `func1` and `func2`, at least not explicitly (likely the two `Optional`s  would come from method calls, though), which does add a little twist to this question the way I see it.

Comment: `return func1().map(Optional::of).orElse(func2());` or, for an expensive `func2` operation, `return func1().map(Optional::of).orElseGet(this::func2);`…

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **java 9+**, you can just use `Optional.or`:

```
return func1().or(() -> func2());
```

In **Java 8**, you may need to create a new Optional from results (use `orElseGet` to avoid eager execution):

```
return Optional.ofNullable(func1().orElseGet(() -> func2().orElse(null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
Object value1 = func1();
return value1.isPresent() ? value1 : func2();
```

Unless I've misunderstood what you're after that will return the value from the first function if it's present, and if it doesn't exist then call `func2()` to return the second optional. You could probably simplify it further to `func1().isPresent` but it made it a little less clear.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something lke this, if i usterstand everything correctly:

```
Optional.of(obj1)
        .filter(obj -> func1().isPresent())
        .orElse(func2());
```

Comment: orElse return the value of Optional. I want to return Optional itself.

Comment: orElse returns result of `func2()` function and it returns Optional, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic version, working with `n` functions:

```
private static <T> Optional<T> firstPresent(Supplier<Optional<T>>... optionals) {
    return Stream.of(optionals)
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

To be used like this:

```
    Optional<String> result = firstPresent(() -> func1(null), () -> func2("abc"));
```